# HVAC: attic heat loss

Tags: hvac, heating, central-heating

Should a ventilated attic (w. Openings in the eaves) be warm in the middle of a cold winter that has a heat pump installed as the heating system for the living area below. If it is warm does that mean there is fixable air leakage in the duct system of the heat pump? The floor of the attic has insulation but the roof does not.

Comment: Is there any equipment up there producing heat? Does the roof get lots of sun on it? Is the insulation sufficiently thick? So many possible questions....

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A diagram would really help us help you; please edit it (and more info if you have it, e.g. your location) into your question.

Comment: The heat pump unit is there and all the insulated ducts run to various ceiling vents in the space below.

Comment: I will rephrase the question : should a properly insulated HVAC heat pump system, installed in a ventilated attic space, lose enough heat to keep that attic warm in the winter or is that a sign of a system that is loosing heated air somewhere through the ducts? I am in new york long Island area.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the sign of leakage from the ducts. Heat will flow from the living space through the ceiling and insulation and the sun will heat the roof. You may have some leakage, but the only way to tell is by (professional) direct testing of the duct work.

Comment: I agree. Insulation ratings are based on the RESISTANCE to heat transfers across it. If you think that through, that means it DOES flow across the insulation.